# Why these two Kotlin coroutines functions are not the same?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Main function:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val channel = Channel<Int>()
    foo(channel)
    for (y in channel) println(y)
    println("Done!")
}
```

This works:

```
fun CoroutineScope.foo(channel: Channel<Int>) {
    launch {
        for (x in 1..5) channel.send(x * x)
        channel.close()
    }
}
```

This does not work (it blocks on channel send):

```
suspend fun foo(channel: Channel<Int>) = coroutineScope {
    launch {
        for (x in 1..5) channel.send(x * x)
        channel.close()
    }
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the documentation of [coroutineScope](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html):

> This function returns as soon as the given block and all its children coroutines are completed

So, writing `coroutineScope { launch { something() }}` is equivalent to just `something()`, because it waits for the `launch`'s completion. This, in turn, means that your second version of `foo` returns only when the loop is completed and the channel closed.

On the other hand, using just `launch` launches an async task, so the code after `foo()` can work concurrently with it.

Actually, if you inline `foo()` in both cases, you will realise that the `launch`-ed coroutine is delimited by `runBlocking`'s scope in the first case, and by `coroutineScope`'s scope in the second case.